# Preserve state of GMSMapView when using custom segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, gmsmapview, swrevealviewcontroller

Currently, i'm using `SWRevealViewController` to create a sidebar and `google map api` for my project.

https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController

Here's the problem. Everytime I switch between `ViewControllers` using the sidebar and back to the `MapViewController` which contains `GMSMapView`, the `GMSMapView` is reloaded to my location (I set it in my `viewDidLoad` method).

How can I prevent `MapViewController` reloads everytime like that ?

---

What I've tried so far:
Make the `MapViewController` becomes a singleton and set it to `destinationViewController` but it doesn't work. All I got is a black screen.

my code for the `custom segue`:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if ( [segue isKindOfClass: [SWRevealViewControllerSegue class]] )
    {
        SWRevealViewControllerSegue* rvcs = (SWRevealViewControllerSegue*) segue;
        SWRevealViewController* rvc = self.revealViewController;

        rvcs.performBlock = ^(SWRevealViewControllerSegue* rvc_segue, UIViewController* svc, UIViewController* dvc)
        {
            if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SegueToMapViewController"])
            {
                dvc = [MapViewController sharedMap]; //singleton
            }
            UINavigationController* nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:dvc];
            [nc setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
            [nc setToolbarHidden:YES];
            [rvc setFrontViewController:nc animated:YES];
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you don't change the map camera position in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`.

If that's not the case, you can save the camera position before you leave the view controller and restore it when the controller is shown again.

Comment: I do thing about it but it's like a tricky way to fix the problem because the `GMSMapView` still reload map data, thus, it costs time and user mobile data.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while from your question, but I run into a similar problem these days and I think I found the way to do preserve the state of the `GMSMapView` (although I don't know if `SWRevealViewController` would make any change).

As you say, the idea is to have a "singleton", but instead of the controller I made it for the `GMSMapView`. Try to make the `GMSMapView` a property of the root `UINavigationController` by making a subclass of it and initialize the map on the `ViewDidLoad` of the subclass.

Interface:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>

@interface TEST1NavigationController : UINavigationController

@property GMSMapView *mapView;

@end
```

Class:

```
#import "TEST1NavigationController.h"

...

@implementation TEST1NavigationController

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:40.7056308
                                                       longitude:-73.9780035
                                                            zoom:15];

    self.mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    self.mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
}

...
```

Then, in each individual controller you can ask to the custom navigation controller for that `GMSMapView` and work with it.

```
#import "TESTMAP1ViewController.h"
#import "TEST1NavigationController.h"

@interface TESTMAP1ViewController ()

@end

@implementation TESTMAP1ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //Retrieve the mapView and assign it to the main view
    self.view = [self mapView];

    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.7056308,-73.9780035);
    marker.title = @"Sometitle";
    marker.snippet = @"Sometext";
    marker.map = [self mapView];

}

-(GMSMapView*)mapView{
    //Returns the view from the Navigation Controller
    return [((TEST1NavigationController*)[self navigationController]) mapView];
}

...
```

This way the state should be preserved inside the controllers of the navigation controller.